# rails downgrade to version 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I tried downgrading rails from `4.0.3` to `3.2.13`using the command

```
gem uninstall rails 

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rails-4.0.3
 2. rails-3.2.13
 3. All versions
>1
```

then again i check rails version it is still `Rails 4.0.3`

Comment: Did you actually uninstalled `rails-4.0.3`?

Comment: yeah i did. when i pressed 1 it said Successfully uninstalled rails-4.0.3

Comment: Try `gem uninstall railties` after that and change your gem version in gem file as `gem "rails", "~> 3.2.13"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall rails as:-

```
gem uninstall railties
```

Select the option of **railties-4.0.3** to uninstall it.

It will uninstall dependencies of rails-4.0.3 and when you check its version.

```
rails -v
```

It will show

```
Rails 3.2.13
```

After uninstalling rails as **gem uninstall rails** doesnot uninstall its dependencies. Due to which it shows the rails version as Rails 4.0.3